# How to know instance id in Idea in breakpoints section?

Tags: intellij-idea, breakpoints, jetbrains-ide

Read https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-breakpoints.html

> To limit breakpoint hits only with particular object instances using instance IDs, check the Instance filters option and type the instance ID value, or click the ellipsis button and specify instance ID in the Instance Filters dialog.

How do i get an instance id ? Where should i look ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the **Variables** view in **Debug** tab.

[image: Debugger variables view]

The instance id is the number after the variable.
So given variable `f1={Foo@432}` the instance id of `f1` is `432`.

Comment: Most likely yes, the id will change from run to run. E.g I tried changing the order of variable declarations and that changed the ids (but when I left the code unchanged the ids stayed the same as well).

Answer (score 2):

to know instance id you should **expand** **this** in **Variables** window of **Debug**. The instance id will be instanceId in {YourClassName@**instanceId**}

In this way, the line that you've set the instance id for which will be suspended just for this instance id.